# Select Values from two combobox from a list of combobox?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0, jcombobox

I have six combobox placed on my form and at same time i want user can select values from maximum of two combobox. 
for this i have take a counter variable which get incremented every time when selectedindex of a combobox get changed but didn't reach to solution.

Can you guys explain how can i do this ?

Comment: Could you share the code you have so far?

Comment: combobox ou dropdownlist?

Comment: do the increment only when selected index is with the item limit (-1< and >last_item_index

Answer (score 1):

I created an example for you. I hope it can be usefull.

ASP.Net Page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Combobox 1</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-1-1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-1-2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Combobox 2</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-2-1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-2-2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Combobox 3</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-3-1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-3-2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Combobox 4</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-4-1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-4-2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Combobox 5</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-5-1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-5-2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Combobox 6</label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Height="19px">
                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-6-1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Combo-6-2</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

ASP.Net Code-Behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["DropdownSelectLimit"] = 0;
        }
    }

    protected void Unnamed1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["DropdownSelectLimit"] != null)
        {
            if ((int)ViewState["DropdownSelectLimit"] < 2)
            {
                int count = (int)ViewState["DropdownSelectLimit"];
                count++;
                ViewState["DropdownSelectLimit"] = count;
            }
            else
            {
                DropDownList dropDown = (DropDownList)sender;
                dropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
                Label1.Text = "You can't select any option anymore";
            }
        }
    }
```

If you have any question just ask me on comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a setup for Winforms as it wasn't complete clear if you wanted it for Winforms or ASP.Net

I will not handle how you should fill a combobox, i'm sure you know how to do this, whether this is filled static or dynamic.

My solution (although quite rude) makes you link a simplified handler named **HandleComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged** to each combobox SelectionChanged event. This can be The SelectedItemChanged, SelectedValueChanged or SelectedIndexChanged.

Quite important: each combo needs a null value.

```
//will hold a list of your combobox names
private List<string> SelectedCombos;

//form load: Link the events to the correct handler
private void Form_Load()
{
    foreach(var combo in Controls)
    {
        if(combo is ComboBox)
            combo.SelectedValueChanged += HandleComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}

//will handle the selectedIndexOrItemchanged event
private void HandleComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(SelectedCombos = null)
        SelectedCombos = new List<string>();

    var combo = (ComboBox)sender;
    if(combo.SelectedValue == null)
        if(!SelectedCombos.Exist(combo.Name))
            SelectedCombos.Remove(combo.Name);
    else
        if(!SelectedCombos.Exist(combo.Name) && SelectedCombos.Count < 2)
        SelectedCombos.Add(combo.Name)

    SetComboAvailability();
}
```

Another function which might be useful, whenever 2 combos are selected, make the enabled state false. This means that your user can only select from the 2 selected combos untill one of them is reset at it's null position. This way your user can only select what is possible.

```
//set the combos availability, less then 2 selections ok, own selection also ok else not ok
private void SetComboAvailability()
{
    foreach(var combo in Controls)
    {
        if(combo is ComboBox)
            combo.Enabled = SelectedCombos.Count < 2 || SelectedCombos.Contains(combo.Name);
    }
}
```

Below a small example of how you could retrieve all your values from the combos based on their names.

```
//Something for handling all the values
private void RetrieveValues()
{
    foreach(var v in SelectedCombos)
    { 
        var combo = this.Controls.Find(v);
        if(combo is ComboBox)
        {           
            //do something with the selectedValue
            var val = combo.SelectedValue; // or selecteditem
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Control {0} has value {1}", combo.Name, val);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't understand something feel free to ask.

Also:

the EventArgs property might change according to the selected event:

do: _comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged+= (TAB TWICE in VS) to see what the automatic code generation looks like. (always handy)

Example:

```
_comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += _comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;

private void _comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```